# Running python scripts only when imported modules are modified

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

Is there a way of running python scripts only when imported modules are modified?

This would be very useful for test automation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the lib and store the value on somewhere on the disk like:

```
import hashlib
with open(hashlib.__file__, "r") as r:
   value=hashlib.md5(r.read())
# do compare here and store the value on disk
```